# imagemin not minifying SVGs

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-imagemin

I'm using `imagemin` with Grunt and it works as expected with PNGs/JPGs, but not with SVGs.

When I add an SVG into my project, Grunt says:

```
>> File "../public/microsite/src/img/Sketch.svg" added.
Running "imagemin:dynamic" (imagemin) task
Minified 0 images (saved 0 B)
```

Is this simply because it can't optimise them any further, or because it's not trying to at all? Even if an SVG can't be optimised, which I doubt is the case, I'd still like it `imagemin` to place it in the `dist` folder.

This is my config:

```
imagemin: {
    dynamic: {
        options: {
            optimizationLevel: 3,
            svgoPlugins: [{ removeViewBox: false }]
        },
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: '../public/microsite/src/img/',
            src: ['*.{png, jpg, svg}'],
            dest: '../public/microsite/build/img/'
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the spaces in the `src` object were invalid. I removed them, which allowed all image files to be minified. `src: ['*.*']` also works.